# exception "error: expected ';' after top level declarator" from ndk-build

Tags: c++, android-ndk

OS:macOS 10.13.3
IDE:Android studio 1.5.1
g++:4.2.1

scene：
I wanna develop with NDK using c++.When I define a c++ class to build,the Gradle Console return an error like below:

```
> src/main/jni/addcomputer.c:23:12: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
jclass Test{
           ^
           ;
1 error generated.
make: *** [build/intermediates/ndk/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/addcomputer/addcomputer.o] Error 1
:app:ndkBuild FAILED
```

and my .cpp like below:

```
#include "com_BTC_ui_JNI.h"
//......
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_BTC_ui_JNI_getString(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{
 return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "mytest-sample-x");
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_BTC_ui_JNI_plus(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jint a, jint b)
{
 return a+b;
}

jclass Test{//this is where the error occur
    private:
        jint mytest;
};
```

When I open a terminal to build a .cpp file which contain a class define,it return a same error.I cannot find the reason.Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Did you mean `class Test`?

Comment: Yes.Just a test.I define it for test.

Comment: The error message says "addcomputer.c", but you mention a ".cpp" file. Could it be that you're compiling as C rather than C++?

Comment: I rename the file suffix from .c to .cpp.that's not the key.

Comment: `jclass` is a pointer type. `jclass Test { private: jint mytest; };` makes no sense.

Comment: "jclass" is a ndk type, which mapped to "class" of c++,I just translate c++ source code to ndk type,but even I compile .cpp file via g++ on terminal ,that error thrown still.so I guess that's a compile problem.

Comment: `jclass` is a `_jclass*`, where `_jclass` is some C++ class. Or, if you're programming in C, `jclass` is a `jobject`, which in turn is a `void*`. So, like I said before, the way you're trying to use `jclass` makes no sense and I'm not sure why you were expecting it to work.

Comment: Because I need translate some java magic to c++ form.I need to define some c++ classes to make the magic smooth,but I first touch this technology, and no reference material show me how to use c++ classes in NDK development process.

Comment: Well, to define a C++ class you use the keyword `class` (or `struct`). `jclass` is for holding references to Java classes; it's not a keyword. You cannot define Java classes in your C++ code, but you can create instances of Java classes that have been defined in your Java code. See [the JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: Good morning,I'm reading.

Comment: Michael,after some basic fix, my .cpp can compile without error,but run failed, always throw exception cannot find implemention of my jni interface, that make me confused.And I read some portion of the document.then I begin to hesitate if I should translate the whole key magic written by java to pure c++ code?Maybe I just need to re-implement the key magic by operate the java class and methods via jni.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error has gone , I just fixed some basic problem.Although the compile process is ok, the running time has occur another error of cannot find implementation of native method.I guess that's caused by compiler.Now I should close this question.Thanks all for focusing this question.